# Is it possible to add additional control to browser "open file" dialog?

Tags: javascript, c++, .net, winapi, dialog

I want to customize "open file" dialog that pops up when I am trying to upload a file. For example, I want to add a button on it which does something when clicked( e.g. pops up another dialog or changes the directory). 
[image]

Comment: Short answer is no you can't

Comment: if you use `IFileDialog` you can do this by call [IFileDialogCustomize::AddPushButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775892(v=vs.85).aspx) - [Customizing the Dialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913(v=vs.85).aspx#customizing)

Comment: Your website is only browsed from Windows?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan we can assume so

Comment: @charlietfl why?

Comment: @RbMm I have to have the dialog object to do that, right? But because it's in chrome's code I don't have the object. Is there a way I can get the handle of that object?

Comment: Do you hate your users that much?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Why brother ? :D Assume I am the only user of my site, and I am doing this for me

Comment: Write your own program then

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could do this when the dialog is opened in your own application.

As you mention javascript and "upload" I assume your frontend is running in a browser. In that case, no, you cannot. That dialog is opened by the browser and you cannot influence it from the client/javascript side.

Comment: I have seen web sites that something different. Instead of regular dialog completely custom dialog was opened. So you are wrong. I want the native dialog but some extra features.

Comment: @RandomUser You have seen a regular browser let the client side javascript manipulate it's file-open dialog?

Comment: no, javascript didnt manipulate. Probably something was installed on the client side, that added something in winapi which changed the native dialog

Comment: the native windows open dialog is changed. nothing done by the browser or javascript

Comment: @RandomUser Maybe you should ask a question exclusively about that. Doing it for a web frontend is a major pain though, as you hope that the browser the person uses, uses the standard dialog *and* is on a version of Windows your software supports *and* the user installed your client executable... so why have a web frontend at all? It would be easier to write your client for that specific system.